# How String builder manage multi threads access to single object and mutability?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, stringbuffer, mutability

how String disadvantage became the advantage as String-builder. i mean i have learned that string are immutable because if suppose there are five String objects and if there is change in one Object then it will reflects in all and may cause run time errors and after that String-Buffer is mutable but at least it is synchronized one thread at time . things are going well and finally now String-builder mutable with multiple threads to access. it so complex to use? how a programmer can manage that.

Comment: Immutable means you can not change object of type String. Now you have to remember the difference between the actual objects and variables in your program. Your variables are simple references ti actual objects. Hope this can help edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuffer` is synchronized that means that all its methods are `syncrhonized`, so it can be safely used in multithreaded environment, i.e. several threads can change and retrieve content of  `StringBuffer` instance safely.

The price of this ability is that when 2 threads access the `StringBuffer` instance at the same time the second thread is blocked until the first thread is dealing with buffer. This means that your multithreaded system becomes in face singe-threaded for this time period. If such situations happen often performance of your system can be much lower than it could be without locks.

`StringBuilder` is not synchronized. This means that if 2 threads change its state simultaneously the result is unpredictable. So you should manage your access policy yourself either by synchronizing methods that provide access to instanceo of your `StringBuilder` or by avoiding multithreaded access, for example by using truly immutable objects (like String) or in-fact immutable objects (e.g. like builder per thread).

Comment: The idea that a StringBuffer should be thread safe was always a dumb idea IMHO and SimpleDateFormat shows that.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, indeed. You are absolutely right. I did not want however to add too much information to the beginner that has a lot of stuff to learn.

Comment: StringBuffer is a pet hate of mine so I try to steer any one away from it ;) Another one is using DataInputStream for text o_O.

Answer (score 1):

*StringBuffer is only thread safe if you call one and only one method.*  SimpleDateFormat uses StringBuffer but is not thread safe (and it was written by the JVM developers). It is not easy to use StringBuffer in a thread safe manner and get it right.

You are better of using StringBuilder which replaced StringBuffer ten years ago and use explicit `synchronized` or a `Lock`. This is mroe likely to be actually thread safe for your use case.

> how to use explicit Synchronized or a lock –

You place a `synchronized` block around your operations

e.g. writing a new line

```
synchronized(sb) {
   sb.append("data: ");
   sb.append(data);
   sb.append("\n");
}
```

or to grab the contents

```
String s;
synchronized(sb) {
    s = sb.toString(); // no simple way to control how many messages you get
    sb.setLength(0);
}
```

> how a programmer can manage that.

Most likely you want a different approach.  This is because there is no way to poll a StringBuilder/StringBuffer and ask it; are you complete? If I read you, can I clear it in a simple manner so the buffer can be reused.  There is no simple way to block if there is no data available. There is also no concurrency for writers.

If you want to share a stream of text between threads, I suggest using a

```
BlockingQueue<String> textStream = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
```

This will be thread safe, support concurrent writing and reading, and you can block waiting for some data and know it is exactly one message.

Comment: how to use explicit Synchronized or a lock

Comment: @ManishVyas Just like any other object, I have updated my answer. Note: this is the only safe way to do it even if you use StringBuffer.

Comment: thank you so much for such a great explanation . i really appreciate it